# Spring application - jdbc commit

Tags: spring, jdbc

I have a Spring application migrating from WebLogic to Tomcat (ucp connection pool). Started noticing a weird behavior where we see SQLs getting executed but not committed but not consistent in different environments. Some of the calls are not annotated with txn but wondering how is jdbctemplate.update committing the transactions if its not annotated with transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weblogic has a specific implementation for committing irrespective of auto commit before a connection is closed.